# Class Instantiation Failed Exception and Run time Exception

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, omnipay

I downloaded and install the omnipay package on my localhost from ([omnipay-nabtransact](https://github.com/sudiptpa/omnipay-nabtransact)). It is working fine on localhost but when I installed it on the live server, I am having errors.

The errors are:-

> (2/2) ClassInstantiationFailedException Unexpected exception when
>   instantiating class.

and

> (1/2) RuntimeException GuzzleHttp requires cURL, the allow_url_fopen
>   ini setting, or a custom HTTP handler.

I am not able to understand what are these errors. When I did the installation on my localhost Laravel FW, it work smoothly. But when I installed it on the live server, I am having trouple fixing it.

Answer (score 2):

Install curl as per your version of php

```
sudo apt-get install php-curl
```

Then restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: this is on my live server and issue is over here. I dont have terminal on my shared hosting that I can install it. is there any other alternative. Thanks

Comment: I was also wondering, then how did it worked on the localhost using Xampp?